# How has the Yearling badge been awarded so soon?

Tags: support, badges

It looks like a few folks have [already been awarded the Yearling badge](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/badges/52/yearling), for 12 months active membership.

Yet according [the Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/homebrewing-beer-wine-etc), this site was only proposed 9 months ago.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe those users were imported from the Stack Exchange 1.0 homebrewing site -- it is rare, but we do sometimes merge with older SE 1.0 sites.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Comment: Right, a bunch of us came from the old BrewAdvice site.